# Ways to have pytest test discovery skip testing methods from imports

Tags: pytest

I have a tests directory with test files inside. One of these test files imports a python module from outside the tests directory. That python module has a method inside of it that leads with test_ . It specifically needs to be that way. Is there a way to skip testing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use --collect-only you can see the paths for the tests being collected. Using that info along with --deselect I was able to skip the test.